# R - map a function to the lower and upper levels of a list simultaneously

Tags: r

Suppose you have a list like this:

```
a <- list("aa" = array(c(c(1, 2, 3), c(3, 2, 1)), dim = c(3, 4)),
          "bb" = array(c(c(7, 8, 9), c(10, 11, 12)), dim = c(3, 4, 2)))
```

How can I use `tidyverse` to turn `a[["aa"]]` into a data frame and make `a[["bb"]]` a list which contains dataframes `a[["bb"]][,,1]` and `a[["bb"]][,,2]`? Is it possible to do all in the same pipe chain, without breaking the pipe?

The following does not work:

```
a %>%
  map(data.frame)
```

since it turns `a[["bb"]]` into a dataframe which instead needs to be a list of dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try writing a custom function for the data that you have.

```
change_to_dataframe <- function(x) {
  if(length(dim(x)) > 2) apply(x, 3, data.frame)
  else data.frame(x)
}

library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

a %>% map(change_to_dataframe)

#$aa
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  1  3  1  3
#2  2  2  2  2
#3  3  1  3  1

#$bb
#$bb[[1]]
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  7 10  7 10
#2  8 11  8 11
#3  9 12  9 12

#$bb[[2]]
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  7 10  7 10
#2  8 11  8 11
#3  9 12  9 12
```

Comment: I applaud the effort but my suspicion is that the use case is much more complicated and at the moment obscure. Or maybe there is no use case?